# Same size children in vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation. All of the children's height is set to `wrap_content`. I would like to make all children have the same height, the height of the biggest child. Is this possible to do?

Comment: you can make them heigth = 0dp and then, make weight= 1

Comment: @Ticherhaz Thank you! Sometimes the simplest answers are hard to remember. I almost went with custom layout so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do to make that item follows its spaces, you can use, `layout:weight`

For example here,

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"/>

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:weight="1"/>

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

To distribute sub views evenly in `LinearLayout`, The [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#equal-weight) give a standard way:

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight of each view to "1".